# Find the set of subsequential limits for...

Tags: real-analysis

1. $b_n= \frac{n^2(-1)^n}{n^2+3}$.
2. $c_n= n^(1+(-1)^n)$

For 2, I know that for even $n$, $c_n=n^2$ and for odd $n$, $c_n=1$ but I'm not sure how to write this as a set.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

$$b_{2n}=\frac{(2n)^2(-1)^{2n}}{(2n)^2+3}=\frac{4n^2}{4n^2+3}\to 1$$

$$c_{2n+1}=(2n+1)(1+(-1)^{2n+1})=(2n+1)(1-1)=0\to 0$$